# Как получить текст из поля Enter Python Tkinter

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

Пишу приложение на Tkinter с использованием классов и столкнулся с проблемой: не могу найти, как получить данные из поля Entry.

```
class Personal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwarg)
        self.geometry('1200x600')
        MainfontStyle = tk.font.Font(family="helvetica 14", size=19, weight="bold")
        ExtrafontStyle = tk.font.Font(family="helvetica 14", size=14)
        MinifontStyle = tk.font.Font(family="helvetica 14", size=10)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Форма записи на посещение',anchor='center', font=MainfontStyle, fg='#c78605')
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text='Форма записи на посещение',anchor='center', font=ExtrafontStyle, bg='#c78605', fg="black")
        EnterDate = tk.Entry(self, font=MinifontStyle)
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Записать", height=3, width=24,  command=self.get_text)
        label.pack()
        b1.pack(pady=10, side = 'bottom')
        label2.pack(anchor="w",padx=40, pady=10)
        EnterDate.pack(anchor='w', padx=48, pady=20)

    def get_text(self): 
        return self.EnterDate.get()
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

> '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'EnterDate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_text(self): 
    return self.EnterDate.get()
```

Всё верно из поля `Entry` информация извлекается методом `.get()`. Однако с чего вы взяли что сможете получить доступ к атрибуту экземпляра класса `self.EnterDate`, заранее не определив его в конструкторе класса `__init__`?.

```
class Personal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        ...
        EnterDate = tk.Entry(self, font=MinifontStyle)
        ...
```

Переменная `EnterDate` здесь является локальной переменной, чтобы была возможность обращатся к ней из других методов этого класса необходимо дописать "self." Перед переменной. Пример:

```
class Personal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        ...
        self.EnterDate = tk.Entry(self, font=MinifontStyle)
        ...
```